# Insert Multiple Checkbox Value in Database Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

how can i insert loop value into database stored all values into array please take a look and suggest me

```
$data['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $data['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $data['password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $data['gender'] = $_POST['gender'];
    $data['dob'] = $_POST['dob'];
    $data['address'] = $_POST['address'];
    $data['country'] = $_POST['country'];
    $data['hobbie'] = $_POST['hobbie'];

$checkElement = "";
    foreach($data['hobbie'] as $check=>$chkValue){
        $checkElement = $chkValue.","."<br>";

        echo $data['hobbie']= $checkElement;
// here i am getting all value

    }
//outside of loop i am getting only last value
```

Comment: Your loop is only referencing the 'hobbie' index of your array: `foreach($data['hobbie'] as $check=>$chkValue){` - is this expected?

Comment: yes i jst want to get the values into $data['hobbie'] what ever in the checkboxes array so that i can directly inserted into table

Comment: how you can directly insert into table with $data['hobbie'];. Since, you don't know how many hobbies are selected. You need to have for loop for multiple selected checkbox. Insertion will be done inside for loop only.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$data['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$data['password'] = $_POST['password'];
$data['gender'] = $_POST['gender'];
$data['dob'] = $_POST['dob'];
$data['address'] = $_POST['address'];
$data['country'] = $_POST['country'];
$Hobbie = $_POST['hobbie'];

$TotalCheckedHobbie=sizeof($Hobbie);
$Hobbies = "";
for($i=0;$i<$TotalCheckedHobbie;$i++)
{
    $Hobbie=$Hobbie[$i];
    $Hobbies=$Hobbie.",";
}
echo $Hobbies;
```

Comment: Hi danish I have already created a function for insertion now i am getting Array ( [name] => Chrish [email] => Chrismarry@gmail.com [password] => 222 [gender] => male [dob] => 08/05/1988 [address] => Mumbai [country] => India [hobbie] => Array ( [0] => Cricket [1] => Hockey [2] => Badminton [3] => Volleyball ) )

these value bt in India[hobbie] i dont want array in want only value that can insert into direct.

Comment: @user4464505: Edited. Check it.